# conditional PDF bivariated Birnbaum Saunders

Tags: distributions, conditional-probability, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function, bivariate

According to theorem 3.1 of this article [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047259X09001122), If $(T_{1},T_{2})\sim BVBS(\alpha_{1},\beta_{1},\alpha_{2},\beta_{2},\rho),$ then:

The conditional PDF of $T_{1},$ given $T_{2}=t_{2},$ is given by:

$$f_{T_1|T_2=t_{2}}(t_{1})=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}\alpha_1\beta_1\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\left[\left(\frac{\beta_1}{t_1}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}+\left(\frac{\beta_1}{t_1}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}\right]*\exp{\left\{-\dfrac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}\left[\frac{1}{\alpha_1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{t_1}{\beta_1}}-\sqrt{\frac{\beta_1}{t_1}}\right)-\frac{\rho}{\alpha_2}\left(\sqrt{\frac{t_2}{\beta_2}}-\sqrt{\frac{\beta_2}{t_2}}\right)\right]^{2}\right\}}$$

My question is:

$$f_{T_1|T_2=t_{2}}(t_{1})=f_{T_1|T_2\leq t_{2}}(t_{1})?$$

or equivalently,

$$P(T_1\leq t_{1}|T_2=t_{2})=P(T_1\leq t_{1}|T_2\leq t_{2})?$$

If this is not true, how to find:

$P(T_1\leq t_{1}|T_2\leq t_{2}),$ If 
$(T_{1},T_{2})\sim BVBS(\alpha_{1},\beta_{1},\alpha_{2},\beta_{2},\rho)$